# geoQuery and get CEL files

Tags: r

im using the geoQuery Package and want to download row CEL files from a GSE.

```
getGEOSuppFiles( "GSE1132" )
```

if get this error :

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 10 elements
```

for me its at the moment not clear how to get the RAW .CEL files.
I thought the best method was `getGEO` for the GSE id and then process the original .CEL files.

Hopefully someone can help me :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check at the relative link [about the GSE1132](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE1132) you'll find, at the end of the page, that

> Supplementary data files not provided.

So when you call the `getGEOSuppFiles()` function it fails.

Raw data like **.CEL** files are normally supplied as *supplementary data files*.